# Count unique value from associative array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

First, thanks for any help.

I've spent countless hours on here and other forums trying to find my exact solution but either 1) I'm not understanding the one's I've read or 2)I haven't found the right answer.

In PHP, I've run a somewhat complex query which returns a set of records similar to:

```
id | name | direction| 
1    aaa    east
2    bbb    west
3    ccc    east
```

I've created an associative array such as:

```
$query=("select * from foo");
$result=mysql_query($query);
$array=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Now, what I need to do seems simple but I'm not grasping the concept for some reason.
I need to loop through the entire $array and return a count of any value that I want to specify and store that count in a variable.

i.e. Show me how many times *east* shows up in the "direction" column and put that in a variable called `$eastcount`.

I've tried various combinations of using `foreach` loops with incremental counts and have tried using `array_count_values` but have not been able to put the pieces together :/

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: Honestly, I've been trying for two days so to list everything would take another 5 days :)  I can't get the count that easily because the actual result set is taken from a subquery...

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` only fetches one row

Comment: Note: The `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Please use `mysqli` or `pdo` instead.

Comment: also...I don't want to add time to the query from mysql because it will have to be run quite often and it will eventually take longer and  longer each time.  I'd rather pull the info from the array.

Comment: Explosion: The array will show all rows if I do a foreach or a "while..." loop.  I'm hoping to combine that concept to get what I'm looking for.

Comment: There is no 'direction' column in your "schema"

Comment: Ann:, thanks I'm aware they are being deprecated but I'm stuck with this for this particular environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// build query
$query=("select * from foo");

// execute query
$result=mysql_query($query);

// declare vars
$east_count = 0;

// iterate through results
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    // grab DIRECTION column value
    $direction = $data['direction'];

    // detect 'east'
    if ($direction == 'east') {

        // increment 'east' count
        $east_count++;
    }
}

// print # of times we had 'east'
echo("direction said 'east' $east_count times");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work (sorry for the lack of code block I'm on my iPhone).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));

Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
query=("select * from foo");
$result=mysql_query($query);

$directions = array();

while($direction = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {
   $directions[] = $direction['direction'];
}

$directionCounts = array_count_values($directions);

//now you can access your counts like this:
    echo $directionCounts['east'];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, of all you should be using mysqli instead. But, anyhow I hope this makes some sense.

```
if ($result) {
    $count = 0;
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row["route"] === "east") {
            $count += 1;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```