# Sort and Count Unique value of Array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a array with thousand values.

`$arr = array('Stone', 'Gem', 'Star', ..., 'Star', 'Rock', 'Salt', ..., 'Metal', 'Cotton', 'Gem',...);`

my problem now is how can I count the values of the array.. for example:

```
Stone = 234
Gem = 231
Star = 123
Rock = 98
Salt = 265
...
```

any idea about this?

Comment: `array_count_values()` [documentation link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), returns the required array and the input array rests untouched

Comment: `array_count_values($array);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count unique value from associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970869/count-unique-value-from-associative-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

`$array_frequency = array_count_values($array);`

The keys are the unique values of your input array, and their respective  values is the number of occurrences of that value in the input array.

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

```
$occurrences = array_count_values($arr);
```

will result in something like:

```
Array
(
    [Stone] => 234
    [Gem] => 231
    [Star] => 123
)
```